# Using Large Function with Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In the following formula, it needs to search for values in the range "A101:A" in the range "DATA!B:B" and get the largest value in the range "DATA!G:G". But it should auto-fill after line 101. But it gives the following error. What do you think could be the problem?
"Array arguments for EQ have different size."

`={"LARGE" ;ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A101:A); ARRAYFORMULA(LARGE(IF(DATA!B:B=A101:A;DATA!G:G;"");1));)) }`

Sample Table:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PAHZirzGcxKJFUrSMiCCc5v7SlUwDtjpmiwl-ATjNwA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a sample sheet with sample data that reproduces this issue.

Comment: Also, B:B is 100 rows larger than A101:A. Maybe you mean B101:B?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it didn't work. I shared the sample table link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PAHZirzGcxKJFUrSMiCCc5v7SlUwDtjpmiwl-ATjNwA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add what is your expected output

Comment: Biggest number of matching names

Comment: Put them in the sample sheet so we have a reference

Answer (score 1):

I want to handle the formula without dragging it down. I solved the problem by sorting the numbers below from largest to smallest. Thanks for the help.

`={"LARGE" ;ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); VLOOKUP(F2:F;SORT(DATA!A2:G; 7;FALSE);7;0);)) }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a filtered version of the DATA table which only contains the value in column A of your original sheet. Then take the largest value with `LARGE`.

```
=large(filter(DATA!$A$1:$G;DATA!$A$1:$A=$A2)
```

However, since you have to generate multiple filtered tables, you cannot use `ARRAYFORMULA`, thus you need to drag down from cell B2.

[image]